# How to get results with where condition in Filament Admin Resource

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel Filament and made a Resource for User model which works fine.

I have a is_admin field in users table which return 0 and 1. I need users with is_admin = 0 but for now , i am getting all of them.

Can i add a where condition in filament to get only required fields.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late for the answer, bit here's an in depth guide.

There are two ways to go about it

#### #1 Pre-filtering query inside the resource

Inside your resource, override the following method:

```php
public static function getEloquentQuery(): Builder
{
    return parent::getEloquentQuery()->where('is_admin', 0);
}
```

#### #2 Global Scope

Filament uses the eloquent interface, so applying a global scope will do the job aswell.

First, create a global scope class inside App\Models\Scopes\ (not a required path, only a suggestion):

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Models\Scopes;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
 
class AncientScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->where('is_admin', 0);
    }
}
```

Then, modify your user model to apply the scope:

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use App\Models\Scopes\AncientScope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new AncientScope);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to add additional where conditions with the built-in eloquent query are as follows:

```
public static function getEloquentQuery(): Builder
{
    return static::getModel()::query()->where('is_admin', 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put `->where('role', '0')` after `return nameModal::query()` at getTablequery(). \

like this

`return nameModal::query()->where('role', '0');`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can extend `getEloquentQuery()` function at related resource class.Since you are talking about User model you can add above function as in the below code example to `UserResource.php`.

```
public static function getEleouentQuery () {
   return User::where('is_admin',0);
}
```

Check [this](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/admin/resources/getting-started#customising-the-eloquent-query) for more